# Polynomial inequality with derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial of degree n with real coefficient and such that $f(x)\geq0$ for every real number $x$

prove that $ f(x)+f'(x)+\dots+f^{(n)}(x)\geq0 $ for all real number $x$.

I thought about the following. Since $f(x)$ is positive for all real number, then $f(x)$ must be even function, with a positive leading coefficient.

Any hints will be appreciated

Comment: Solution on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h274078p1483750. The essential hint is also given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195664/problem-about-sum-of-polynomials#comment2434029_1195664.

Comment: Thank you,sorry I didn't know it was asked here before